# is restart necessary after a config change in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, configuration

After a configuration change is it necessary to restart the db so that the new config take effect?

The configuration was changed via this command:

> db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand( { setParameter: 1, cursorTimeoutMillis: 300000000 } )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188) and [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/parameters/), it does not mention of requiring a restart.

**ISSUE SUMMARY**

> Client cursors that are no longer used may not be closed by the
>   server. These cursors continue to consume resources inside mongod. By
>   default, inactive cursors expire after 10 minutes, this option makes
>   it possible to configure this timeout.

**RESOLUTION DETAILS**

> By specifing the cursorTimeoutMillis option, administrators can
>   configure mongod or mongos to automatically remove idle client cursors
>   after a specified interval. The timeout applies to all cursors
>   maintained on a mongod or mongos, may be specified when starting the
>   mongod or mongos and may be modified at any time using the
>   setParameter command. Consider the following examples.

**cursorTimeoutMillis**

> New in version 3.0.2.
>
> Default: 600000 (i.e. 10 minutes)
>
> Available for both mongod and mongos.
>
> Sets the expiration threshold in milliseconds for idle cursors before
>   MongoDB removes them; i.e. MongoDB removes cursors that have been idle
>   for the specified cursorTimeoutMillis.
>
> For example, the following sets the cursorTimeoutMillis to 300000
>   milliseconds (i.e. 5 minutes).

But some users saw the value did not take effect till restart.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/_nYxRY0iDr0/HeRpqRIIBwAJ